# How can i get my string replace with to equal the value of a form input?

Tags: javascript, php, function

Im trying to use string replace to change a line of code within my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceScript() {
    var toReplace = 'LINE OF CODE 333';
    var replaceWith ='??????????';
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
}
</script>
```

How can I get my...

```
var replaceWith ='??????????';
```

...to equal the value of an input from a form on the page?

Note the input value is auto populated on page load and the user does not enter in there own email address.

Comment: This question could be simplified to ['how do I get the value of an input field'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value) correct?

Comment: well im trying to insert the replace with value equal to that of an inputs value

Comment: Sure, but once you have the text from the input field it's not hard to use that as the value for `replaceWith`?

Comment: well there a little more...the inputs value holds the value of an email...so im trying to modify a scripts line to include this email value thats where the sting replace is comes in

Comment: You're trying to do a find and replace on actual JavaScript code? Why would you need to do that?

Comment: no its for a mysql bit of code im trying to modify

Comment: You've lost me entirely... Good luck though.

Comment: every comment you have added has made this less clear.

Comment: $query = "select Name from myTable where Name ='$NAME' ";

you can use this in your sql and change the $NAME with the user input var

Comment: "*Note the input value is auto populated on page load and the user does not enter in there own email address*" so why isn't this done at the server before the code reaches the client? Vastly more efficient and less problematic to do it there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an input such as `<input id="inputValue" type="text" />`

The general approach is to use a DOM function like `getElementById()` or `querySelector()`, and access its value with the `value` property.

Your code could be as simple as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceScript() {
    var toReplace = 'LINE OF CODE 333';
    var replaceWith = document.getElementById('inputValue').value;
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
}
</script>
```

Comment: i do believe this is what I'm looking for

Comment: @Steve Marty already gave this answer in the first comment to your question

Comment: Arbitrarily using a regular expression to replace markup in a page using the innerHTML property is not a particularly good idea. It will remove every event listener added by *addEventListener* and may have other undesirable consequences.